# How to get the query result in an object executed over SSH

Tags: node.js, ssh, electron

I am trying to get the result of an query executed over SSH in an object to parse and show in the website. So far I have been able to execute the query and in the console log I can see the table output. Below is the code snippet I am using in node JS. This is an app build with electron framework.

I am executing this from my client `ssh.executeCommands(['mysql -uroot -prtdb -e "select * from tableName"'], onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback)`

The executeCommands function is

```
executeCommands(commands, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback) {
    const onSuccess = data => {
        if (onSuccessCallback)
            onSuccessCallback(data);
    };

    const onError = () => {
        if (onErrorCallback)
            onErrorCallback();
    };

    let client = new Client();
    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Connection :: ready');
        client.shell((err, stream) => {
            if (err) onError();
            stream.on('close', () => {
                console.log('Stream :: close');
                client.end();
                onSuccess();
            }).on('data', (data) => {
                onSuccess(data);
                console.log('data: ' + data);
            }).stderr.on('data', data => {
                console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
                onError();
            });
        });
    });

    client.on('error', () => {
            client.end();
            onError();
        }
    );
    this.initClient(client);
}
```

The data object I am receiving has a lot information, but I wanted to have only the query result.
This is the console log of the data object [image]

Comment: What is printing out `Successful query execution`?

Comment: Oh! that's a console info before the console log!

Comment: Why not use an actual database client instead (e.g. `mysql2` which supports custom connection streams)?

Comment: I don;t have direct access to that server, only ssh login to execute query. Anyways, I figured it out by returning the object as a string.